# WPF ListView show Image

Tags: wpf, image, listview, controls, bind

I have a simple class that contains a string and an *WPF* `Image` control:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public System.Windows.Controls.Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm binding a list of instances of this class to a `ListView`.

What I would like to do now is make `ListView` display the *Image* property.

I've tried settings `DisplayMemberPath` to *Image*, but this shows the `ToString` value of *Image* instead (`System.Windows.Controls.Image`).

How can I make it actually show the control?

Here's the *XAML* code:

```
<ListView Name="listView1" DisplayMemberPath="Image" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `DataTemplate` that uses a `ContentPresenter` to display the image:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Image}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Ah yes! That was what I was looking for :) Thanks!

I did try using ListViewItem, but this somehow introduced weird behavior when selecting items.